# script to calculate directory size and delete the oldest log inside if crosses the threshold usage?

Tags: linux, bash

script to calculate directory size and delete the oldest log inside if crosses the threshold usage? There is a log rotation inside this folder and it the size crosses the threshold limit say 10GB I want to delete the some oldest file . Help me with the script. I know how to delete the files older than x days but I want to set threshold limit and delete some old log.

Answer (score 1):

`du` tells you disk usage. For finding files older than x days, use `find` with `-ctime` or `-mtime`. The `-delete` option to `find` deletes the found files directly.

(Yes I know this isn't a complete answer. Neither is this a complete question.)

Comment: thank you for the reply, I want to delete log files only if the total size of log is greater than the threshold limit that I set

Comment: @Özzesh: The idea of StackOverflow is to help you with *concrete* problems you might have run into while trying to solve a problem, not to write your solution for you from whole cloth. That would require 1) a formal specification, and 2) a paycheck. ;-) Also, you might want to try `logrotate` or other ready-made solutions...